# else statement or return in ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, return

I have next method:

```
def self.authorize(auth_data)
  provider = Provider.find_or_create_by(name: auth_data['name'], uid: auth_data['uid'])

  if provider.user.present?
    provider.user
  else
    user = User.find_or_create_with_oauth(auth_data['info'])
    provider.update(user: user)
    user
  end
end
```

And I can replace `if-else` condition with `if-return`:

```
def self.authorize(auth_data)
  provider = Provider.find_or_create_by(name: auth_data['name'], uid: auth_data['uid'])

  return provider.user if provider.user.present?

  user = User.find_or_create_with_oauth(auth_data['info'])
  provider.update(user: user)
  user
end
```

I don't know what is more `ruby` style, or preferably in general.

Comment: They're both OK, it's programmer choice.

Comment: Well, i like the first one, if there are no bad smells, i'll use it.

Comment: In both cases I see a smell in appearing to return different things. Write it how you like as long as the value returned is `provider.user`.

Comment: @David, the Ruby style guide condemns the use of mixed metaphors.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I have no idea what that means. I'm sure the guide also condemns impenetrable aphorisms.

Comment: @David, I was referring to "see a smell", a febble attempt at levity. Oh, well.

Comment: @Cary: I knew I was missing something, as the eunuch said to the hooker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also consider:

```
def self.authorize(auth_data)
  provider = Provider.find_or_create_by(name: auth_data['name'], uid: auth_data['uid']
  provider.update(user: User.find_or_create_with_oauth(auth_data['info'])) unless provider.user.present?
  provider.user
end
```

Alternatively, you might find this more readable:

```
def self.authorize(auth_data)
  provider = Provider.find_or_create_by(name: auth_data['name'], uid: auth_data['uid'])
  unless provider.user.present?
    user = User.find_or_create_with_oauth(auth_data['info'])
    provider.update(user: user)
  end
  provider.user
end
```

Comment: I know, but it's less readable.

Comment: Tastes vary, but there's something to be said for a single point of return when it comes time to debug.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i think we clarify this topic.